How to include fisheye undestortion into the H264 encoder of picamera2?
I am currently working on a project that requires minimal CPU usage on the rpi5 and a wide field of view. I need multiple outputs as described in one of the examples. To reduce the overhead I thought I could combine the encoder function of the H264 encoder with a fisheye undestorter from the cv2 library by applying a wrapper class around the H264 encoder that intercepts the frames before encoding and undestorts them before passing them to the encoder. Unfortunately the frames I can intercept are in a format I don't quite understand. Also, I don't really know how to get the undistorted frames back into the pipeline.
At the moment my code crashes during the reshape operation because the frame has the size 540000 but I try to reshape the array with the stride included. Therefore I have printed the format and of the frame and the format of the stream configuration.
The frame shape is: (360, 500, 3), dtype: uint8, min: 0, max:255.
However, the stream config is format: RGB888, size: (500, 360), stride: 1536, framesize: 552960.
I would actually like to convert the frame into a format in which I can apply my undestortion. I also don't know how to get the frame back into the same format as before and feed it back into the stream.
Did anyone had similar issues or an alternative approach to undestort frames while ueseing picamera2? Thanks in advance.
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from picamera2 import Picamera2
from picamera2.outputs import FfmpegOutput
from picamera2.encoders import H264Encoder
import time

class H264EncoderWithUndistortion(H264Encoder):
    def __init__(self, map1, map2, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Initializes the encoder with undistortion and optional debugging.
        :param map1: First undistortion map for cv2.remap.
        :param map2: Second undistortion map for cv2.remap.
        """
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.map1 = map1
        self.map2 = map2

    def _undistort_frame(self, raw_frame):
        """
        Applies undistortion to Bayer raw frames.
        :param raw_frame: Raw Bayer frame as a numpy array.
        :return: Undistorted Bayer frame as a numpy array.
        """
        return cv2.remap(raw_frame, self.map1, self.map2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    
    def _encode(self, stream, request):
        # Access stream configuration
        stream_config = picam2.stream_configuration(stream)
        height, width = stream_config["size"]
        stride = stream_config["stride"]

        # Access the raw frame buffer
        frame = request.make_array(stream)

        #print frame properties
        print(frame.size)
        print(f"Frame shape: {frame.shape}, dtype: {frame.dtype}, min: {frame.min()}, max: {frame.max()}")
        print(picam2.stream_configuration("main"))
        # Handle stride
        frame_with_stride = frame.reshape((height, stride))  # Include padding
        valid_width = width * 3  # Actual bytes per row
        frame = frame_with_stride[:, :valid_width].reshape((height, width, 3))
        
        # Temporarily skip undistortion for debugging
        undistorted_frame = self._undistort_frame(frame)

        # Debug undistorted frame data
        print(f"Undistorted frame min: {undistorted_frame.min()}, max: {undistorted_frame.max()}")

        # Visualize the frames for debugging
        cv2.imshow("Undistorted Frame", undistorted_frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
            print("Quit visualization")
        cv2.imshow("Raw Frame", frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
            print("Quit visualization")

        # Encode the undistorted frame
        super()._encode(stream, request)

# Define the output folder and file path
output_folder = os.path.expanduser('~/Documents/recordings')
os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)
output_file = f'{output_folder}/DEMO.mp4'

# Initialize the camera
picam2 = Picamera2()
video_config = picam2.create_video_configuration(
    main={"size": (500, 360), "format": "RGB888"},
    controls={"FrameRate": 30, "Saturation": 0.0}
)
picam2.configure(video_config)

# Load fisheye calibration data
K = np.array([
    [247.490210, 0.365535, 252.210439],
    [0.000000, 247.791476, 179.082768],
    [0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000]
])
D = np.array([
    [-0.053639],
    [0.119409],
    [-0.234838],
    [0.138188]
])
h, w = 360, 500
new_K = cv2.fisheye.estimateNewCameraMatrixForUndistortRectify(K, D, (w, h), None)
map1, map2 = cv2.fisheye.initUndistortRectifyMap(K, D, np.eye(3), new_K, (w, h), cv2.CV_16SC2)


# Create the custom encoder
encoder =H264EncoderWithUndistortion(map1, map2, bitrate=400000)

# Set up the output
output1 = FfmpegOutput(output_file)
encoder.output = [output1] #--> would define multiple outputs

# Start recording
picam2.start_encoder(encoder)
picam2.start()
    
time.sleep(10)

# Stop recording
picam2.stop_encoder()
picam2.stop()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print(f"Recording saved to {output_file}")

